# Is it possible to run Mike Bostock’s Solar Terminator with Canvas instead of SVG?

Tags: canvas, svg, d3.js

I am trying to run Mike Bostock’s Solar Terminator (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4597134#index.html) with the illustrative orthographic projection.
That looks o.k.

But with modifying this SVG-version to Canvas-drawing I get in trouble. 
When I try the normal ctx.arc-command it will draw a normal circle. It does not position and project the circle correct on the globe.

I tried the following code section, but this will show only the globe without the shading effect.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(70, 130, 180, 0.3)";  // night-style: steelblue and opacity
ctx.beginPath(),
  path(circle.origin(antipode(solarPosition(new Date)))),   
  ctx.fill();
```

Should it be necessary to add the canvas context in the circle-command, like the following code section:

```
var circle = d3.geo.circle()
  .context(ctx)         
  .angle(90);
```

But this is not yet implemented?

I thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var circle = d3.geo.circle().angle(90);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(70, 130, 180, 0.3)";  // night-style: steelblue and opacity
ctx.beginPath(),
path(circle.origin(antipode(solarPosition(new Date)))()),   
ctx.fill();
```

(Note the extra parens to execute the result of the .origin method)

This worked for me without any other changes.